# Is there a new Instagram data source?

Tags: facebook, instagram

Now that Instagram data is no longer public, is there a way of getting data via a third party? I know that you can get Facebook data via datasift but I can't find a source for Instagram data. I know that you can make an application on Instagram that allows individuals to share their own content with 3rd party apps, but I want to see demographics/market data/most frequency/trends etc. How would I go about getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSift does provide access to Instagram data through their Managed Sources product; http://dev.datasift.com/docs/products/stream/features/sources/managed-sources

You are able to either bring your own Instagram App for authentication, or create user tokens against DataSift's App. You then monitor for Instagram posts based on users, tags or locations